# How to enable audit on access to files (rwx) in SLES9

Tags: files, suse, sles, audit

How can I enable audit on access to specific files in Suse Linux Enterprise 9?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at [SUSE's official doc](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/singlehtml/audit_quickstart/audit_quickstart.html#sec.audit.qs.enable)

Another useful source of info is [auditd's man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) which says that all the specific file configurations are in `/etc/audit/audit.rules`

Comment: Thanks, but sles 9 has not /etc/audit/audit.conf. I use this in sles 11

Comment: If you have rpm try `rpm -ql <audit's package name>` that will show you the list of files installed by rpm and there should be something related with the rules, I don't think that a very complex software as audit won't have any kind of configuration file or the rules, hope it helps